# Is it posible to use taxonomy terms in Context module?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

We are developing a Drupal 8 site and we need to create an specific sidebar with Context module using Taxonomy Term. In D7 module version is very easy: you can select an specific taxonomy term... but in Context for D8 we cannot find this option. We only find Vocabulary.

Is it not possible in D8? Or in other words... how we can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at 
[Using Block Visibility Groups to Create Conditional Layouts in Drupal 8](https://dev.acquia.com/blog/using-block-visibility-groups-to-create-conditional-layouts-in-drupal-8/28/03/2016/10126) about solution,
and the
[Term condition](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_condition) module,

it works for me.

Comment: A wise man once said "There's a module for that. Don't use it." @Steven Nord's answer is preferable in my opinion.

Comment: Have this "wise man" ever use Drupal? ;-)
@Steven Nord's post is not the answer it is a workaround with limitations. 
What if:
there are 20 terms in node?
terms have special characters? yeah, another workaround use TID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Request Path (System) in Context for Drupal 8 if you create a URL Alias Pattern you want to target. Works fine for me.